# Optimize this code of adapter's overriden method getItemCount()

Tags: java, performance, android

How can I optimize this code of adapter's overriden method getItemCount()  into simpler form?

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount() == 0 && data != null ? 1 : super.getItemCount();
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some context? What is `data`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with 'simpler form'? You want to beatify or optimize performance?

Comment: @dfzwze I want to beautify

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. It has nothing to do with code reviewing.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen I find the help center unclear about reviewing code layout. The reason I decided to answer this question anyway is because there is a potential performance optimization as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code Beautification is suggestive. This is how I would write your code. There is also a possible performance optimization by only calling `super.getItemCount()` once.

- be consistent with parentheses (I'm using a different rule for methods and conditions, but feel free to use your own preference as long as you are consistent)
- create one variable to store the item count
- get the item count you would like to return from the base class
- determine predicate from the perspective of either

  - (A) the edge case value of item count, when `itemCount == 0`; an inner condition is used to determine the new value
  - (B) the combined condition that yields a different result `itemCount == 0 && data != null`

snippet A

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int itemCount = super.getItemCount();
        if (itemCount == 0) 
        {
            itemCount = data != null ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return itemCount;
    }
```

snippet B

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int itemCount = super.getItemCount();
        if (itemCount == 0 && data != null) 
        {
            itemCount = 1;
        }
        return itemCount;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just post code. Explain also the benefits of your chosen code layout. Now, the method naming suggests that `itemCount` clashes with super class member name. I would use `actualItemCount`, `adjustedItemCount` or better yet, some other form that describes the purpose of the overriding implementation (which we unfortunately don't know). I find the latter form better, as it groups the conditions that affect `itemCount` neatly into the same if-statement. The reader doesn't have to combine statements from multiple lines to figure out what happens.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen (A) Fair enough, it was lacking some description (B) This is something we, unfortunately don't know because of the lack of information from the OP